# Constraint Sum Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math

The problem I am trying to solve has a table of items:

```
Item | x | y | z | ... | n
================
A    | 2 | 3 | 1
B    | 6 | 6 | 8
C    | 9 | 2 | 1
D    | 1 | 5 | 7
.
.
.
w
```

The values of `{x, y, z, ..., n}` can be arbitrary and there can be an arbitrary number of rows and columns.

You would have constraints such that when you combine items together the sum is:

```
1. 7 <= sum(x) <= 10
2. 10 <= sum(y) <= 15
3. 8 <= sum(z) <= 10}
```

and

```
4. The number of items is 2 <= numItems <= 10
```

One possible solution is: `A + B`  (x = 8, y = 9, z = 9)

The goal is to find all possible combinations that satisfy this. Or if that would take too long just some very small subset possible just one.

My question is is there any decent algorithm to solve this? This isn't a homework question or anything, it's for a personal project of mine. I've been trying to think of a good way of solving this but always seem to end up with very inefficient solutions. Hopefully I'm missing something.

Comment: 8 <= sum(x) <= 10} should be 8 <= sum(z) <= 10} right? and the Items are fixed to A,B,C,D only?

Comment: Are you trying to find any combination that satisfies the contraints? Or is the goal to find the best combination that satisfies them? (for some definition of best)

Comment: Ultimately I would want ALL combinations that satisfy. But I may need to settle for just using the first combination that is found. The constraints on the range for `numItems` is variable as well.

Comment: @Kunukn fixed it thanks. And no the number of items is not fixed. I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Note that this problem is NP-complete. With a single column x, sum(x)=K and 1<=numItems<=infinity you have the subset-sum problem.

Comment: @EyalSchneider I had a feeling that was the case... And YES it is the sub-set sum problem I can't believe I didn't see that. If you want to put that in the answer I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is NP-complete. You can easily reduce [Subset-Sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) to this problem as follows.

For a given input S,k of the subset-sum problem:

- Define a single column X containing all values in S
- Require `k<=sum(X)<=k`
- Require `1<=numItems<=|S|`